# MySQL query issue with left joining a table with the results of two other tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to `select` data from one table with the results of the data that is coming out from `joining two different tables`, but I am getting an error and I can not figure it out:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname,lastname) AS staffname
FROM `cms_users`
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(a.firstname," ",a.lastname) AS clientname, b.doa
FROM `cms_clients` a
INNER JOIN `cms_question_report` b
ON a.id = b.cid
WHERE b.doa < '2015-04-15 23:00:00' AND b.doa > '2015-04-09 00:00:00') incidents
```

The error I am getting is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 9

But I don't even have a `LIMIT 0,30` in my query.

Comment: Then that is not the query producing the error. How do you execute it?

Comment: @juergend I am running the query on phpmyadmin,  so there aren't any other queries running while i'm running this one I believe.

Comment: That right join is incomplete. You need to specify the joining columns. I can't say what they are without seeing the schema of cms_users because you aren't selecting an id column.

Comment: phpMyAdmin adds a LIMIT clause to prevent it from displaying too many results.

Comment: Can you post the schema of cms_users?

Comment: @ChipDean can't due to NDA, but it has an id for every user, a first name and a last name fields.
I tried inner join and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is incomplete. You are missing the joining columns for your right join. See below, but you must replace PRIMARY_KEY with the primary key for your cms_users table. Also make sure that i.id is the correct joining column for the two tables.

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname,lastname) AS staffname
FROM `cms_users`
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(a.firstname," ",a.lastname) AS clientname, b.doa
FROM `cms_clients` a
INNER JOIN `cms_question_report` b
ON a.id = b.cid
WHERE b.doa < '2015-04-15 23:00:00' AND b.doa > '2015-04-09 00:00:00')  
AS i ON i.id = cms_users.PRIMARY_KEY
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: It worked, here's the complete query from my end:

SELECT CONCAT(firstname,lastname) AS staffname, d.clientname, d.doa
FROM `cms_users` c
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(a.firstname," ",a.lastname) AS clientname, b.doa, b.user_id
FROM `cms_clients` a
INNER JOIN `cms_question_report` b
ON a.id = b.cid
WHERE b.doa < '2015-04-15 23:00:00' AND b.doa > '2015-04-09 00:00:00') d
ON c.id = d.user_id

Thanks.